# Selenium Python - The element I'm looking for cant be found even though it exists in Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, yahoo

I am working with a school project where I need to obtain the analyst price targets estimates of certain stocks from the Yahoo Finance Website (this is mandatory).

When I tried to use it by beautiful soup I couldn't scrape it (I believe JS is adjusting the page as it loads), so I turned to selenium to obtain such data. However when I'm trying to obtain the elements through the XPATH, it returns error as if it doesn't exist. I am using EC in case it needs to load, but its not working. I've tried modifying the wait times up until 2 minutes, so that is not the issue

Code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BBAJIOO.MX?.tsrc=fin-srch")
driver.delete_all_cookies()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col2-11-QuoteModule-Proxy"]/div/section/div')))
```

Anyone have an idea as to why this is happening? and how can I obtain such ratings?

Image below of desired ratings

[image]

This is the example of the HTML Code:

```
<div aria-label="Low  60 Current  64.59 Average  69.25 High  76.8" class="Px(10px)">
    <div class="Pos(r) Pb(30px) H(1em)">
        <div class="Start(75%) W(25%) Pos(a) H(1em) Bdbc($seperatorColor) Bdbw(2px) Bdbs(d) T(30px)"></div>
        <div class="Pos(a) H(1em) Bdbc($seperatorColor) Bdbw(2px) Bdbs(s) T(30px) W(100%)"></div>
        <div class="Pos(a) D(ib) T(35px)" data-test="analyst-cur-tg" style="left: 27.3214%;">
            <div class="W(7px) H(7px) Bgc($linkActiveColor) Bdrs(50%) Z(1) B(-5px) Translate3d($half3dTranslate) Pos(r)"></div>
            <div class="Bgc($linkActiveColor) Start(0) T(5px) W(1px) H(17px) Z(0) Pos(r)"></div>
            <div class="Miw(100px) T(6px) C($linkActiveColor) Pos(r) Fz(s) Fw(500) D(ib) Ta(c) Translate3d($half3dTranslate)"><span>Current</span>&nbsp;<span>64.59</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Pos(a) D(ib) T(-1px)" data-test="analyst-avg-tg" style="left: 55.0595%;">
            <div class="Pos(r) T(5px) Miw(100px) Fz(s) Fw(500) D(ib) C($primaryColor)Ta(c) Translate3d($half3dTranslate)"><span>Average</span>&nbsp;<span>69.25</span></div>
            <div class="Pos(r) Bgc($tertiaryColor) W(1px) H(17px) Z(0) T(6px) Start(-1px)"></div>
            <div class="W(8px) H(8px) Bgc(t) Bd Bdc($seperatorColor) Bdrs(50%) Z(1) B(-6px) Pos(r) Translate3d($half3dTranslate)"></div>
        </div><span class="W(6px) H(6px) Bgc($tertiaryColor) Bdrs(50%) Z(0) B(-5px) Start(0) Pos(a) Translate3d($half153dTranslate)"></span><span class="W(6px) H(6px) Bgc($tertiaryColor) Bdrs(50%) Z(0) B(-5px) Pos(a) Translate3d($zero153dTranslate) Start(100%)"></span></div>
    <div class="Ov(a) Fz(xs) Mt(10px) C($tertiaryColor)">
        <div class="Pos(r) Fl(start) Fz(xs) C($tertiaryColor) "><span>Low</span>&nbsp;<span>60.00</span></div>
        <div class="Pos(r) Fl(end) Fz(xs) C($tertiaryColor) "><span>High</span>&nbsp;<span>76.80</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One obvious reason is that the xpath is just wrong.  How did you get that xpath?  Can you show us an example of the section of html you're looking for?

Comment: I Edited the question, for more visibility on the code

Comment: That html does not contain any element with `id="Col2-11-QuoteModule-Proxy`.  In fact, none of those elements have an `id` attribute at all.  So, why are you trying to find an element that does not exist?

Comment: Where did you get that HTML? It's not from the page you linked.

Comment: This is a school project so we're not going to give you the answer. First, you need to clean up your question and sync up the HTML and the URL you provided. Then you need to update your code with a locator that actually matches the page. Until you've done that, we can't really help you.